# Creating borders within the specified margins

Tags: tikz-pgf, margins

I've been trying to get borders for specific pages for my thesis, using tikz. Unfortunately, the borders exceed the margins specified, and since I have to submit a bound copy of the thesis, this is creating problems.

Here is a snippet of what I've been trying

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[top=1in,bottom=0.75in,left=1.25in,right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}  

\begin{titlepage}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture} [scale=\marginparwidth/1.5in*1.5,overlay,remember picture]           
    \draw [line width=0.5mm ]   
    ($ (current page.north west) + (1in, -1in) $)
    rectangle
    ($ (current page.south east) + (-1in,1in) $);
\end{tikzpicture}
My university 
\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

Can anybody help me out with this issue?

Comment: Use the tikzpagenodes package.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [`tikzpagenodes`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzpagenodes) package which gives you a family of nodes associated to the text area:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[top=1in,bottom=0.75in,left=1.25in,right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}

\begin{document}  

\begin{titlepage}
\begin{tikzpicture} [overlay,remember picture]           
    \draw [line width=0.5mm ]   
    (current page text area.north west)
    rectangle
    (current page text area.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}

\noindent My university 
\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm getting the following error:
LaTeX Error: File 'tikzpagenodes.sty' not found

Comment: @user1556826 you don't have the package installed. You can use your system package manager (if available) to automatically install it, or you can perform a manual installation [`from CTAN`].

Comment: @user1556826 You're welcome!